# React useEffect Dependecy releated Problem

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, use-effect

In React I have used useEffect to fetch data. But I have confusion when I have to mention the dependency and when I have to keep it empty

Comment: Dependency array controls when `useEffect` callback runs, every time anything in the dependency changes, the callback runs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` which:

1. Empty dependency array when you need it runs once on the first time when mounted (ex: initialize data,...).
2. Not-empty dependency array when you want it runs when anything in the dependency changes (ex: trigger some API calls when state changes,...).

But you should check out the docs for further information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).